# Reduce sum of Gauussian distribution to a single G.P.D

Tags: probability

Given, $r=r_1+r_2$, $r_1=N(\mu_1,\sigma_1)$ and $r_2=N(\mu_2,\sigma_2)$. Then $r=N(\mu,\sigma)$. Could someone direct me to books where $\mu,\sigma$ are derived in terms of $\mu_1,\sigma_1,\mu_2,\sigma_2$? I am new to this area so have failed to do an informed google search for this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see the [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_normally_distributed_random_variables) about sum of normally distributed random variables on Wikipedia